# Cannot cast from FragmentActivity to ListFragment

Tags: android, fatal-error, android-listfragment

This error shows up when i do this:

This is in the MainActivity:

```
ListView lv = ((ListFragment) getActivity()).getListView();
```

but if I don't cast it to that the app crashes and I get

```
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289): Process: com.titanhash.teamdoge, PID: 17289
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at com.titanhash.teamdoge.WorkersFragment.onCreate(WorkersFragment.java:70)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-02 22:35:00.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I will post the rest of the code If you guys need it. Ooh also I am calling the list fragment from the MainActivity with:

This is in the MainActivity

```
case 3:
return WorkersFragment.newInstance("Workers");
```

And the ListFragment instance:

This is in the ListFragment

```
public static WorkersFragment newInstance(String text) {
    WorkersFragment pageFragment = new WorkersFragment();

    return pageFragment;
}
```

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

BIG - EDIT:

Here is the activity code:

```
package com.titanhash.teamdoge;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SuchActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_such);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.such, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return TeamdogeFragment.newInstance("Teamdoge");
        case 1:
            return PoolFragment.newInstance("Pool");
        case 2:
            return UserFragment.newInstance("User");
        case 3:
            return WorkersFragment.newInstance("Workers");
        }
        return TeamdogeFragment.newInstance("Teamdoge");

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the ListFragment code:

```
package com.titanhash.teamdoge;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WorkersFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DASHDATA = "getdashboarddata";
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_PERSONAL = "personal";
    private static final String TAG_WORKERS = "workers";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_HASHRATE = "hashrate";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray workers = null;

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    public static WorkersFragment newInstance(String text) {
        WorkersFragment pageFragment = new WorkersFragment();

        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.worker_layout, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_HASHRATE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SuchActivity.this);
            //pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            //pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            //pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            JSONObject jsonObject;

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    //JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Get the root JSONObject
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Get the JSON object named query
                    //JSONObject getpoolstatusJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("getpoolstatus");
                    JSONObject getpoolstatusJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("getdashboarddata");

                    // Get the JSON object named results inside of the query object
                    //JSONObject dataJSONObject = getpoolstatusJSONObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONObject dataJSONObject = getpoolstatusJSONObject.getJSONObject("data");

                    // Get the JSON object named quote inside of the results object
                    JSONObject personalJSONObject = dataJSONObject.getJSONObject("personal");

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    workers = personalJSONObject.getJSONArray(TAG_WORKERS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < workers.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = workers.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_HASHRATE);
                        //String address = workers.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        //String gender = workers.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        //JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                        //String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                        //String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                        //String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, "ID: " + id);
                        contact.put(TAG_USERNAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_HASHRATE, email + " kH/s");
                        //contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_USERNAME,
                            TAG_HASHRATE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }


}
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

```
package com.titanhash.teamdoge;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class WorkersFragment extends ListFragment {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://teamdoge.com/index.php?page=api&action=getdashboarddata&api_key=5a0a4793431873828540ae6ddad556075b169180d5b16023a41daec8530b890f&id=2317";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_DASHDATA = "getdashboarddata";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_PERSONAL = "personal";
private static final String TAG_WORKERS = "workers";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String TAG_HASHRATE = "hashrate";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray workers = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

public static WorkersFragment newInstance(String text) {
    WorkersFragment pageFragment = new WorkersFragment();

    return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.worker_layout, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_HASHRATE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SuchActivity.this);
        //pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        //pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        JSONObject jsonObject;

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                //JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Get the root JSONObject
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Get the JSON object named query
                //JSONObject getpoolstatusJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("getpoolstatus");
                JSONObject getpoolstatusJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("getdashboarddata");

                // Get the JSON object named results inside of the query object
                //JSONObject dataJSONObject = getpoolstatusJSONObject.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONObject dataJSONObject = getpoolstatusJSONObject.getJSONObject("data");

                // Get the JSON object named quote inside of the results object
                JSONObject personalJSONObject = dataJSONObject.getJSONObject("personal");

                // Getting JSON Array node
                workers = personalJSONObject.getJSONArray(TAG_WORKERS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < workers.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = workers.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_HASHRATE);
                    //String address = workers.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    //String gender = workers.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    //JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    //String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    //String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    //String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, "ID: " + id);
                    contact.put(TAG_USERNAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_HASHRATE, email + " kH/s");
                    //contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_USERNAME,
                        TAG_HASHRATE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: where are you writing that casting code? I mean in which method?

Comment: A fragment is not an Activity, they are completely different. Really not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What I need to do is i guess call the listfragment so that it shows up on the screen and executes its json parser.

Comment: If you are trying to populate listview in fragment then use `ListView lv = getListView();` inside fragment.

Comment: post where you have that code the activity code

Comment: @Ketan when I do that, that is when i get the Fatal Exception.

Comment: @user3148262 show the code where you this 

`ListView lv = ((ListFragment) getActivity()).getListView();`

Comment: @Raghunandan I did it is in the ListFragment I changed it to ListView lv = getListView(); (might not post until morning its getting late)

Comment: @user3148262 so now what is the problem?

Comment: @Raghunandan Now I get the FATAL ERROR in the error log posted up top.

Comment: @user3148262 move the code in oncreate to onActivityCreated

Comment: Totally off-topic, but you are revealing too much information, that might your cost those that hired you. :)

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski I'm really just making this for myself. There isn't  any information that anyone can do anything with.

Comment: @user3148262 copy paste my codes both java code and xml layout code and it will work. no need to change anything except add the proper import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:Content view not yet created
```

Move the code in `onCreate` to `onActivityCreated`. Override `onActivityCreated`.

Edit:

```
public class WorkersFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://teamdoge.com/index.php?page=api&action=getdashboarddata&api_key=5a0a4793431873828540ae6ddad556075b169180d5b16023a41daec8530b890f&id=2317";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DASHDATA = "getdashboarddata";
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_PERSONAL = "personal";
    private static final String TAG_WORKERS = "workers";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_HASHRATE = "hashrate";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";
    JSONArray workers = null;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    public static WorkersFragment newInstance(String text) {
        WorkersFragment pageFragment = new WorkersFragment();

        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.worker_fragment, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
//                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);
//                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, name);
//                in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, cost);
//                in.putExtra(TAG_HASHRATE, description);
//                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }



    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog

            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try
           {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            // HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mbbangalore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");     

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            if (_response!= null) {

                    //JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Get the root JSONObject
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);

                    // Get the JSON object named query
                    //JSONObject getpoolstatusJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("getpoolstatus");
                    JSONObject getpoolstatusJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("getdashboarddata");

                    // Get the JSON object named results inside of the query object
                    //JSONObject dataJSONObject = getpoolstatusJSONObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONObject dataJSONObject = getpoolstatusJSONObject.getJSONObject("data");

                    // Get the JSON object named quote inside of the results object
                    JSONObject personalJSONObject = dataJSONObject.getJSONObject("personal");
                   workers = personalJSONObject.getJSONArray(TAG_WORKERS);


                    for (int i = 0; i < workers.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = workers.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_HASHRATE);
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, "ID: " + id);
                        contact.put(TAG_USERNAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_HASHRATE, email + " kH/s");

                        contactList.add(contact); 
                 }
             }
             }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_USERNAME,
                            TAG_HASHRATE }, new int[] { R.id.textView1,
                            R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

wokers_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: Ok so I did that and when I do in the fragment it still crashes. Sorry if I a being a pain but I don't understand why it is doing it.

Comment: @user3148262 it will work post your updated code. Th exception says that you view is not yet created and yet you try to call `getListView`

Comment: I can't post it until later today. Just got a ft of snow and I need to go shovel. =/

Comment: ok so I moved everything from `onCreate` and created a new `onActivityCreated` but I cannot get it to work. First of all it wont compile because it wants me to get rid of the regular `onCreate` and it also wants me to get rid of `onCreateView`

Comment: ok so The ListFragment doesn't give me anymore errors but now it is back to the same old error. In the MainActivity `return WorkersFragment.newInstance("Workers");` says it cant convert from ListFragment to Fragment

Comment: @user3148262 if you can't post your updated code including import statements don't expect further help. the log is clear cannot convert ListFragment to fragment!.

Comment: @user3148262 `public Fragment getItem(int position) {` What is the return type here? Its Fragment. What is `WokersFragment` a `ListFragment`. Makes sense??

Comment: yes I get that. But my question is, is what do I have to do to make it work? Create another getitem?

Comment: @user3148262 make workers fragment a fragment. have listview in worker_layout initialize it an use the same

Comment: @user3148262 pls check the edit. I have given you a working solution. Rest is upto you to modify to make it work lie the way you want

Comment: I tried that before but since you cannot have a listview inside of a fragment unless it is a listfragment the `setListAdapter` throws an error. I get `The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type WorkersFragment.GetContacts` which is obvious since it cannot be defined because it is not a ListView. And also it is not possible to cast it to a `ListView`.

Comment: @user3148262 where do you see? Pls re- look @ `onPostExecute`. I said its a workign code. It works i tried before posting. Pls look at my code tell me where i have `setListAdapter`??. see this `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`. Stop asking for everything and take a look at the code closer

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have to check out the differences between the two to see how you did it but thanks again! And This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast the `Activity` to a `Fragment`; they are completely different, and you are already inside the `Fragment` instance.

You can't call the `getList()` method from `onCreate()`, because the `View`s aren't initialized at this point; you should move that logic to `onViewCreated()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this: `((ListFragment) getActivity()).getListView();`

The `ListView` you're looking for is in the `ListFragment` you are hosting in that `Activity`.

Time to go back to school…

Please review the documentation for a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) and how to [communicate](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) between Fragments (and Activities).

The answer is there and it will help you understand the problem.